# How to properly use QOpenGLBuffer.PixelPackBuffer with PyQt5

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qopenglwidget

I am trying to read the color buffer content of the default framebuffer in PyQt5 using pixel buffer object given by the [Qt OpenGL](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-index.html) framework.

It looks like the reading is unsuccessful because the end image always contains all zeros. There's very little examples with pixel buffers and PyQt5, so I was mostly relying on this [c++ tutorial](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html) explaining pixel buffers, specifically section `Example: Asynchronous Read-back`.

My code goes something like this:

```
class GLCanvas(QtWidgets.QOpenGLWidget):
      # ...


      def screenDump(self):
            """
            Takes a screenshot and returns a pixmap.

            :returns:   A pixmap with the rendered content.
            :rtype:     QPixmap
            """
            self.makeCurrent()

            w = self.size().width()
            h = self.size().height()

            ppo = QtGui.QOpenGLBuffer(QtGui.QOpenGLBuffer.PixelPackBuffer)
            ppo.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer.StaticRead)
            ppo.create()
            success = ppo.bind()
            if success:
                  ppo.allocate(w * h * 4)

                  # Render the stuff
                  # ...

                  # Read the color buffer.
                  glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT)
                  glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0)

                  # TRY1: Create an image with pixel buffer data - Doesn't work, image contains all zeros.
                  pixel_buffer_mapped = ppo.map(QOpenGLBuffer.ReadOnly)
                  image = QtGui.QImage(sip.voidptr(pixel_buffer_mapped), w, h, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
                  ppo.unmap()

                  # TRY2: Create an image with pixel buffer data - Doesn't work, image contains all zeros.
                  # image = QtGui.QImage(w, h, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
                  # bits = image.constBits()
                  # ppo.read(0, bits, w * h * 4)

                  ppo.release()


            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)

            return pixmap
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any success after a couple of days, so I decided to implement color buffer fetching with pixel buffer object in C++, and then use [SWIG](https://www.swig.org/papers/PyTutorial98/PyTutorial98.pdf) to pass the data to Python.

I'm posting relevant code, maybe it will help somebody.

CPP side

```
// renderer.cpp
class Renderer{
    // ...

    void resize(int width, int height) {
        // Set the viewport
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);


        // Store width and height
        width_ = width;
        height_ = height;

        // ...
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // Returns the color buffer data in GL_RGBA format.
    GLubyte* screenDumpCpp(){

        // Check if pixel buffer objects are available.
        if (!GLInfo::pixelBufferSupported()){
            return 0;
        }

        // Get the color buffer size in bytes.
        int channels = 4;
        int data_size = width_ * height_ * channels;
        GLuint pbo_id;

        // Generate pixel buffer for reading.
        glGenBuffers(1, &pbo_id);
        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo_id);
        glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, data_size, 0, GL_STREAM_READ);

        // Set the framebuffer to read from.
        glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);

        // Read the framebuffer and store data in the pixel buffer.
        glReadPixels(0, 0, width_, height_, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

        // Map the pixel buffer.
        GLubyte* pixel_buffer = (GLubyte*)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);

        // Cleanup.
        glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);  
        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &pbo_id);

        return pixel_buffer; 
    }

    // Returns the color buffer data in RGBA format as a numpy array.
    PyObject* screenDump(){

        // Get screen dump.
        GLubyte* cpp_image = screenDumpCpp();
        int channels = 4;
        int image_size = width_* height_ * channels;

        // Setup dimensions for numpy vector.
        PyObject * python_image = NULL;
        int ndim = 1;
        npy_intp dims[1] = {image_size};

        // Set up numpy vector.
        python_image = PyArray_SimpleNew(ndim, dims, NPY_UINT8);
        GLubyte * data = static_cast<GLubyte *>(PyArray_DATA(toPyArrayObject(python_image)));

        // Copy screen dump to python space.
        memcpy(data, cpp_image, image_size);

        // return screen dump to python.
        return python_image;
    }
};


// glinfo.cpp
const GLInt GLInfo::glVersionInt(){ ... }
GLV GLInt::GLV(int major, int minor){ ... }
bool GLInfo::pixelBufferSupported(){
    const GLint version = GLInfo::glVersionInt();
    bool supported = false;

    if (version >= GLInfo::GLV(1, 5) && version < GLInfo::GLV(3, 0)){
        supported = true;
    }
    else if (version >= GLInfo::GLV(3, 0)){
        GLint extensions_number;
        glGetIntegerv(GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS, &extensions_number);
        std::string pixel_buffer_extension("GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object");
        while (extensions_number--) {
            const auto extension_name = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(glGetStringi(GL_EXTENSIONS, extensions_number));
            std::string extension_name_str(extension_name);
            if (pixel_buffer_extension == extension_name) {
                supported = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return supported;
}
```

Python side

```
# ...

class MyCanvas(QOpenGLWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        # Get renderer from c++
        self._renderer = Renderer()

    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        self._renderer.resize(width, height)

    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ...
    canvas = MyCanvas()
    canvas.show()

    width = canvas.width()
    height = canvas.height()
    data = canvas._renderer().screenDump()

    image = QtGui.QImage(data.data, width, height, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGBA8888)
    new_image = image.mirrored()

    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(new_image)
    pixmap.save(path) 

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```